# Read a value of an object by its parent's index

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Say I have this json:

```json
"myObject" : {
  "trans": {
    "somekey": {
      "name": "i want this value"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I access "i want this value" without knowing the name of "somekey"?

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11922384/13084463), I understood it can be done with indexing:

```
myObject.trans[0].name
```

But I am getting an `undefind`. Why is that?

Comment: Is there always a single key in the "trans" object?

Comment: `myObject.trans[0]` means you're trying to get the first item in an array but `myObject.trans` is an object. You cannot get the "first" key of an object as that is a meaningless term in that context.

Comment: because `trans` is not an array but an object. Objects don't have indexes they have keys.

Comment: @derpirscher Ok, so say I don't know the name of "someKey" but still want the value of "name" and I know it is the first one, what can I do?

Comment: Hint: `{ x: {y : ...} }` translates to `x.y` while `{ x: [ { y: ... } ] }` translates to `x[0].y`. Note `{` -> `.` and `[` -> `[n]`. You can also do `x['y']` instead of `x.y` but thats' because objects allow that kind of notation as well.

Comment: How do you define "first one"? Because per definition object-keys don't have a ordering. Can there be more than one key in `trans`? Can you modify this datamodel? If yes, I'd suggest to make `trans` an array instead of an object.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array` if you are not sure about the key. So that you can use `.find()` method to find the element without knowing the index or key.

```js
var myObject = {
  "trans": [{
    "name": "i want this value"
  }]
}

console.log(
  myObject.trans.find(item => item.name === "i want this value").name
)
```

Comment: Hm, as I understand the question, the value `"i want this value"` is not yet known. So how can you use it in the search?

Comment: ***How can I access "i want this value" without knowing the name of "somekey"*** @derpirscher you asked how to access without knowing "somekey". Since you never mentioned that "i want this value" is not known, I suggested an Array approach.

Comment: First of all, I'm not OP. And second: Why would someone search for a value in an array, if he already knows that value? It seems quite obvious, that OP want to get the (yet unknown) value of `myobject.trans.somekey.name` without knowing the key `somekey`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) which returns a list of an objects keys. You can then use this array of keys to select the name key from the parent object.

```js
const myObject = {
      "trans" : {
        "somekey" : {
          "name" : "i want this value"
        }
      }
    };

const transKeys = Object.keys(myObject.trans);
const nameValue = myObject.trans[transKeys[0]].name;

console.log(nameValue);
```

Note - this will only work if you are sure that `trans` will only have one child, and that child will always have the property `name`. If `trans` contains multiple properties which may or may not contain name, you can use the array of keys to iterate through each of the properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the structure of how your object looks, this is what I would suggest:

```
let myObject =   {
    "trans": {
        "somekey": {
            "name": "i want this value"
      }
    }
}

let finalValue;

Object.values(myObject.trans).forEach(val=>{
    if(val.name){
        finalValue = val.name;
    }
})

console.log(finalValue)
```